# How to apply HTTPS for certain web page

Tags: php, codeigniter, https

Recently I am trying to learn how to apply HTTPS, SSL inside for certain website to prevent our client's information been stolen by hackers.

I searched some related source and tutorial from Google. I applied them into `.htaccess` and change the Listen port which allocated inside `httpd.conf`.

Yet, I still can't find a solution. Therefore, I seek for help at here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in code instead of using htaccess.

You can create a helper function that will redirect the page to be over SSL, which you call from your controller.

In your helper;

```
function force_ssl() {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
        $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller;

```
class Whatever extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('your_ssl_helper'));
    }

    public function index() {
        force_ssl();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I give you reply tomorrow?
Because I need to try it inside company.

Comment: @Blackie sure, no probs.

Comment: Thank you @Rooneyl.
It works like a charm.

I'm so sorry I'm not enough reputation to vote you up.
A million of thanks!

Comment: thanks!! ^^
Is there any security can be apply into CodeIgniter which is important for user?

Comment: @Blackie I don't really understand what you are asking (don't forget to accept the answer if it has worked for you)

Comment: I mean, CodeIgniter got provide some securities such as XSS filtering, cross-site security right?
Does CI provide more security function?

Oh okay. Sorry about that. :D

Comment: @Blackie xss can be be on each input by setting the form validation rules (xss_clean) or can be set globally in the config. You will have to look at the docs for more info.

Comment: that one I know how to use already. But then, I heard my friend said hack still can use injection and expose database information. Is there a nice way to prevent? I had referred some articles, but it is too complicated to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a virtual host in Apache? Something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName yoursite.example.com
    # Configuration for web site 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes, I did.
But once I did it, my XAMPP corrupted.

Comment: Then your virtual host config is invalid. You must include certificate in virtual host. Here are [some examples](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts).